# Updating multiple columns in a certain row SQL LITE

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have 4 methods all to update separate parts of data in a certain row. (I did this because I'm new to SQ Lite and Android). How would I condense all of this into one method?

```
public void updateInt(int id,String newName, String oldName){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
            " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
}

public void updateAuth(int id,String newAuth, String oldAuth){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL3 +
            " = '" + newAuth + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL3 + " = '" + oldAuth + "'";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
}

public void updateUser(int id,String newUser, String oldUser){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL5 +
            " = '" + newUser + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL5 + " = '" + oldUser + "'";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
}

public void updateLocation(int id,String newLocation, String oldLocation){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 +
            " = '" + newLocation + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL4 + " = '" + oldLocation + "'";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: do you update the 4 columns of the row in separate time or you call all these 4 methods in sequence(once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd leave it as is.

Since each expression sets different things in **different rows** (all of the `WHERE` conditions are different) it can't really be merged.

Comment: I'm passing the same variable for id into each of the methods so it's very redundant. It would make more sense to just combine it into one function

Comment: Without knowing the schema, since the `WHERE` clauses are different then each one will be different rows. Now if it is that your WHEREs have redundant bits in them (i.e. `id` is the only thing you care about) then the answer is different.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `SQLitedatbase` **`update`** convenience method, you could use :-

```
public void updateAll(int id, 
        String newName, 
        String newAuth, 
        String newUser, 
        String newLocation) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL2,newName);
    cv.put(COL3,newAuth);
    cv.put(COL4,newLocation);
    cv.put(COL5,newUser);
    SqliteDatabase sqliteDatabase = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    sqliteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
        cv,
        COL1+"=?",
        new String[]{Long.toString(id)}
    );
}
```

- This assumes that you want to update all columns.

If you wanted to just update certain columns but still use the one method, then :-

```
public void updateAll(int id, 
        String newName, String oldName
        String newAuth, 
        String newUser, 
        String newLocation) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    if (newName != null && newName.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL2,newName);
    }
    if (newAuth != null && newAuth.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL3,newAuth);
    }
    if (newLocation != null && newLocation.length() > 0) { 
        cv.put(COL4,newLocation);
    }
    if (newUser != null && newUser.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL5,newUser);
    }
    if (cv.size() > 0) {
        SqliteDatabase sqliteDatabase = this.getWriteableDatabase();
        sqliteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
            cv,
            COL1+"=?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(id)}
        );
    }
}
```

- This again assumes that you know the respective id.

e.g.

```
yourdbhelper.updateAll(id, "Fred","",null,"France");
```

would :-

- update the row;

  - replacing COL2 with **Fred**,
  - not change COL3 (length of passed string is less than 1)
  - not change COL4 (null passed)
  - change COL5 to **France**

If you wanted to update only if the old??? values matched then you could use :-

```
public void updateAll(int id, 
    String newName, String oldName,
    String newAuth, String oldAuth,
    String newUser, String oldUser,
    String newLocation, String oldLocation) {

    ArrayList<String> whereargs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(id)));
    StringBuilder whereclause = new StringBuilder(COL1+"=?");

    if(oldName != null && oldName.length > 0) {
        whereclause.append(" AND " + COL2 + "=?");
        whereargs.add(oldName);
    }
    if(oldAuth != null && oldAuth.length > 0) {
        whereclause.append(" AND " + COL3 + "=?");
        whereargs.add(oldAuth);
    }

    if(oldUser != null && oldUser.length > 0) {
        whereclause.append(" AND " + COL4 + "=?");
        whereargs.add(oldUser);
    }

    if(oldLocation != null && oldLocation.length > 0) {
        whereclause.append(" AND " + COL5 + "=?");
        whereargs.add(oldLocation);
    }

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    if (newName != null && newName.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL2,newName);
    }
    if (newAuth != null && newAuth.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL3,newAuth);
    }
    if (newLocation != null && newLocation.length() > 0) { 
        cv.put(COL4,newLocation);
    }
    if (newUser != null && newUser.length() > 0) {
        cv.put(COL5,newUser);
    }
    if (cv.size() > 0) {
        SqliteDatabase sqliteDatabase = this.getWriteableDatabase();
        sqliteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
            cv,
            whereclause.toString(),
            whereargs.toArray(new String[whereargs.size()])        
        );
    }
}
```

**!Note the code is in-principle and hasn't been tested so it may have some errors.**